# How to publish an ALREADY created/published infopath form to another type (Content Type or Admin Approved template)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I'm trying to follow the steps to publish my list form (infopath-ized) as a Content Type so a subsite can 'see it' (add it to the Infopath Form Web Part in a subsite's webpage). unfortunately the steps say i should be able to select "File, Publish, Sharepoint Server". but i only see "Sharepoint List" and "Export Source Files" in the Publish menu.

so i can't get down to where the steps say i should see a page of options in the publishing wizard where you can select 'form library, site content or admin-approved template.

is it not possible to change the publishing scheme once you've published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list form cannot be published as a content type, as far as I'm aware. List forms have only a subset of the functionality of browser forms, and they are tied to (and stored within) "their" list, whereas browser forms are stored in a forms library.

Edit: here is the anchor syntax to open the InfoPath list form from a sub-site in overlay mode.

```
<a href="#" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '/Lists/YourList/NewForm.aspx', title: 'Add item' }); return false;">Add an item</a>
```

You need to adjust the path to your list, of course.

Comment: so there is no way for a list form to be viewable in a subsite?

Comment: Not as an InfoPath list form, no. But you could have a button or link that opens the form in overlay mode. That works from a sub site. You'd need a bit of JavaScript to pull that off. I'll post the code above.